# Set Proxy automatic configuration script from command prompt

Tags: proxy, local-area-network, windows-command-prompt

I'm running into a problem where I'm running a script to clear the automatic configuration settings found below,and it does clear the windows when you check through the UI.

However, it doesn't seem like it actually takes effect and I have to manually go in to the LAN settings page and click ok in order for my script to take effect.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I can't set anything to a new configuration script unless the clear settings script works correctly the first time.

Below is the script I'm running and the pictures of what I'm seeing after running the script but not taking effect.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
```

[image]

[image]